# Is there any way to invert the background which is in an outside of the bounty box co-ordinates. using python?

Tags: computer-vision, python-imaging-library, opencv3.0

Pythonists!

I'm a beginner-pythonist.

I'm using YOLO V3 to recognize and localize image with bounty boxes. It'll give bountybox co-ordinates.

Is there an anyway to invert the image background which is an outside of the bounty boxes by using any one one of python imaging library?

Let's assume the situation where, we have recieved multiple bountybox co-ordinates from an image.

I don't have much time to explore the new things. i'm doing projects for an xyz company.

Thanks in adavance.!

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask In short, *"Hello fellow coders"* and *"Thanks in advance!" are discouraged. Questions should be accompanied by code and any sample images/data necessary for answerers to assist you.

Answer (score 2):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# second parameter is 0. it means to read the image in grayscale
# just for example
img = cv2.imread(path_to_your_image, 0)
```

lets suppose that your image is

[image: original image]

you can get an inverted image using the following code

```
img_inverted = 255 - img
```

[image]

and your bounding box is

```
x, y, w, h = 100, 50, 120, 120
```

`x`, `y` are top-left coordinate of the bounding box. `w`, `h` are width and height of the bounding box

you can invert the image background which is an outside of the bounding boxes by using this code

```
img_inverted[y:y+h, x:x+w, ...] = img[y:y+h, x:x+w, ...]

# note that the first axis is `y` and the second is `x`
# ... — means take all the channels
# in grayscale we have only one channel,
# but this will work even if you have RGB image
```

[image]

same will work for multiple bounding boxes

```
bboxes = [
    [100, 50, 120, 120],
    [10, 10, 20, 50],
    [300, 30, 50, 50],
    [300, 130, 50, 50]]

for bbox in bboxes:
    x, y, w, h = bbox

    img_inverted[y:y+h, x:x+w, ...] = img[y:y+h, x:x+w, ...]
```

[image]